# Google Scripts - Copy existing spreadsheet and rename it

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using Google Scripts. I am attempting to, upon form submission, copy and existing spreadsheet (not the spreadsheet the form submits to) and rename it based upon a cell in the submission.

I assumed that the way to do this is to identify the spreadsheet to be copied by its ID. Here is a bit of the code. Both variables (newUserSS and UUID) define properly.

```
  var newUserSS = "1-bOW_eIKc-dt8pX9YlwpjZTtwjEDYOPxcasSxQ9ndvM";
  var UUID = sheet.getSheetValues(newLine,2,1,1);
  newUserSS.copy(UUID);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the spreadsheet using the retrieved Spreadsheet using the spreadsheet ID.

The detail information of `copy()` is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#copyname).

#### Modified script :

```
var id = "1-bOW_eIKc-dt8pX9YlwpjZTtwjEDYOPxcasSxQ9ndvM";
var newUserSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
var UUID = sheet.getSheetValues(newLine,2,1,1);
newUserSS.copy(UUID);
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.